# d3 how to render 15 circles every line

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a dataset containing 250 values for every value I want to render one circle for every data value but after every 15th circle I to shift to the next line and start rendering from there. How can I do this? All the circles must be of same radius 3. my code:

```
var svg = d3.select('#dots')

var dataSet = [];

var initialValue = 259



for(var i=0; i<=initialValue; i++){
dataSet.push(i)
}

var circle = svg.selectAll('circle')
    .data(dataSet)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr({
        r: 3,
        cx:function(d, i){
        if(i<=15){
        return i*10+10
        } 
        },
        cy: function(d, i){
        if ( i<=15) {
        return 20
        } else  {
        return 30
        }
        },
        fill: 'red'
    });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Jag/1885/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [modulus](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arithmetic.asp) operator:

```
.attr({
    r: 3,
    cx:function(d, i){
    return 30 + (i%15)*10

    },
    cy: function(d, i){
    return 10 - ((i%15)-i)
    },
    fill: 'red'
});
```

Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/pL187dc0/

The logic of using modulus is that the result will come back to 0 for every multiple of 15. For example, this code:

```
var i = -1;
while (i++ < 200) console.log(i%15);
```

Will generate in the console:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
11, 12, 13, 14, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14...
```